Setting REDO Log retention time in Debezium Oracle Connector
We are running a Kafka implementation with the main goal of streaming data from Oracle using the Debezium connector. We have already configured it and made it run successfully for a while. However, we are currently encountering the following error every 2 hours:
Online REDO LOG files or archive log files do not contain the offset scn.
Our DBA has configured the redo logs to be moved by size rather than at specific time intervals, which is causing challenges in fine-tuning and killing the operation.
Is there a configuration in Debezium that can address this scenario? If not, what would be a good strategy to avoid impacting both Oracle and Kafka?
Thanks in advance.

REDO logs are fixed in size and are always rotated as they fill up. When the last log in the rotation is full, the first log is overwritten and the cycle starts over. If you are running in ARCHIVELOG mode then a copy of each REDO log is made to an archive location when it is full and rotation moves to the next REDO log. This is not configurable by clients. Is your database running in ARCHIVELOG mode?

Maybe a little late but for those who has the same problem. Use heartbeat option. Helped us solve the problem. Thank you @pmdba, your comments helped us realize we had a wrong understatement.
